# C# Extract "200", "204" HTTP Resposne URL With Webbrowser control?

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

Is there a way to get the 200, 204 HTTP Response with the webbrowser control? When I navigate to a website I get back 2 urls 1 is "200" and the other is "204" but I can only see those URL's via Fiddler webbrowser doesn't redirect to them it does it in the background, But I need those URL's to string to be able to extract from them some data Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think you can; however, you could send a HttpWebRequest with method HEAD (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/314594/use-httpwebrequest-to-get-remote-pages-title?rq=1) and then check the response codes on that.

Comment: _"When I navigate to a website I get back 2 urls"_ - what do you mean? Can you re-word your question to explain what is happening and what you expect to happen? What do you need those URL's for and where are they requested from?

Comment: @CodeCaster I navigate to webpage after a i click on a button I can see 2 new requests/responses 200 & 204 (With Fiddler) I don't see it in the webbrowser(No Redirections or anything) it all happens in the background but I know they are there because of fiddler, I would like grab the urls to a string.

Comment: @dash I know how to do it n httpwebrequest I really need it in webbrowser

Comment: I need the whole URL of the invisble requests or how are they called? (respones?), I was thinking maybe it counts as a referrer, So If maybe can to grab the last referrer it will work (This is how i do it in httpwebrequest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer the following page

[http status code in web browser control](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/f0558d26-fee9-44e3-9a14-0148e34824a5/)

Comment: I don't need the status code I need the whole URL of the it, I was thinking maybe it counts as a referrer, So If maybe can to grab the last referrer it will work (This is how i do it in httpwebrequest)